# Is the intersection of Boolean sublattices a Boolean sublattice?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-theory, boolean-algebras

Let $L$ be a boolean lattice, $A$ and $B$ sublattices of $L$ that are
themselves boolean lattices, and suppose that $I = A \cap B$ is
nonempty.

Is $I$ a boolean sublattice of $L$?  Is it a homomorphic image or
retract of $L$?  If so, is there an explicit characterization of its
upper and lower bounds?

$I$ is clearly a distributive sublattice of $L$, $A$, and $B$, and is
bounded above in $L$ by $1_A \sqcap 1_B$ and below by
$0_A \sqcup 0_B$.

For example, consider the boolean lattice consisting of the powerset
of $\{1,2,3\}$ with intersection as meet and union as join.  Let $A$
be the boolean sublattice containing $\{1,2\}$, $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$, and
$\{\}$, and $B$ the boolean sublattice containing $\{1,2,3\}$,
$\{1\}$, $\{2,3\}$, and $\{\}$.  Then $I$ is the boolean sublattice
containing $\{1\}$ and $\{\}$, but not containing the upper bound
$1_A \sqcap 1_B = \{1,2\}$.

More generally, if $A$ and $B$ are intersecting intervals of $L$, then
$I$ is a boolean sublattice and a retraction of $L$ to $I$ takes an
element $x$ of $L$ to the element $(x \sqcap 1_I) \sqcup 0_I$ of $I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L$ be the lattice of all subsets of $\{1,2,...\}$. Let $X=\{2^k3^l:k,l\in\omega\}$ and $Y=\{2^k5^l:k,l\in\omega\}$. Let $A=\{a\subset X:$ $a$ is finite or $X\backslash a$ is finite$\}$, and $B=\{a\subset Y:$ $a$ is finite or $Y\backslash a$ is finite$\}$. Then $A$ and $B$ are Boolean sublattices of $L$, but $A\cap B=\{a\subset X:$ $a$ is finite and $a\subset\{2^k:k\in\omega\}\}$ is not a Boolean sublattice of $L$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A\cap B$ contains a greatest element $y$ and another element $x$ then
$$\neg x := y\setminus x\quad \in A\cap B$$
is a "complement" of $x$ within $A\cap B$.

So in that sense, $A\cap B$ will always be a Boolean sublattice.

Comment: The existence of such a greatest element $y$ is guaranteed if $A$ and $B$ are complete lattices, but does the conclusion hold if they need not be complete? Let $A = Pfc(2Z)$ denote all finite and cofinite subsets of the
multiples of 2.  Then $A$ is a bounded boolean sublattice of the
powerset $P(Z)$, but is not complete because the intersection of all
cofinite subsets of $2Z$ that lack only elements of $4Z$ is the set
$2Z - 4Z$, which is not finite or cofinite.  If  $B=Pfc(3Z)$, then $I = Pfc(6Z)$, which is a bounded boolean sublattice.

Comment: @JonDoyle right, I don't know either in the incomplete case